# FabricJS How to capture object hover while object:moving

Tags: hover, fabricjs, mousemove

Using [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com)

I would like to capture the `mouse:over` event while the canvas is firing the `object:moving` event. Is that possible. Seems like only one event can be fired at a time.

**The reason** I want to do this is I would like to do "something" when my shape is dragged over another one.

thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I found a way. Not sure if its ideal yet, especially if there are many objects on the canvas.

The basic idea is to figure out ***which objects are under/at the current mouse position*** while moving a **selected object** around.

- **isDropZone**: A property (metadata) added to an object to indicate that its a drop zone.

Here is the code:

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function (e) {                       
        var objs = canvas.getObjects();
        var mouse = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
        for (var i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
            if (objs[i].containsPoint(mouse) && objs[i].isDropZone) {
                console.log("Object is in drop zone");
            }
        }               
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue and I am using `findTarget` method, which basically does what you were doing, but is also checking for things like the `perPixelTargetFind` option. It will also run through objects within groups in case you are using groups.

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function(event) {

   /**
    * findTarget Method that determines what object we are clicking on
    * @param {Event} e mouse event
    * @param {Boolean} skipGroup when true, group is skipped and only objects are traversed through
    */
    var hoverTarget = canvas.findTarget(event, false);

    console.log(hoverTarget);

});
```